# MS Access Partial Match 2 Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In MS Access I need to exclude a LARGE list of words (table-B) if they are contained anywhere (partial match) within Table-A. I know how to use IS NULL with wildcard but this will not work as my list is well over 1,000 records to exclude. See Example Below...

TABLE-A:
best red apples here
best ripe apples here

TABLE-B:
red apples

QUERY1 (RESULTS):
best ripe apples here

NOTE: I'm using MS Access 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from tablea as a
where not exists (select 1
                  from tableb as b
                  where instr(a.phrase, b.word) > 0
                 );
```

Note:  this cannot take advantage of indexes, so performance will no be good on largish tables.

Comment: Are you suggesting to list all the phrase words within the code above?

Comment: For some reason Access will not accept the code above, so still not resolved.

Comment: Figured out how to get the query string you provided to work. Thank you very much. Is there another solution for very large tables?